# Fetching data from an API: Avoid multiple calls

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-context

I am working on a tutorial wherein I am trying to build a twitter like application with a Django backend and a React frontend. I am following the tutorial steps but trying to implement my solution with the hooks and context api.

There is one place I am stuck on. So on the home page, when say a guest user visits the website, I want to show all tweets. But on a profile page, I want to show only the tweets of a particular user. I am using react-router to pick up the username from the URL.

The problem I am facing is, on the second route i.e. the one with the username, 2 api calls are being made to the backend. One is when the tweets-context is first created and the second when the username gets set. Because of this, since both of calls are being made to the backend, whichever call gets fulfilled by the backend later, gets rendered on the screen. Ideally I would want to make the call on this route only after the username has been set.

How do I avoid these multiple calls?

Here is the link to the sandbox with my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pascal-tbf0s

The actual code might not run on another machine because the APIs are not hosted anywhere, they are on my local machine only. But I hope someone can identify the issue and provide a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let talk about your problem first. In your code, you have two contexts are "user" and "tweet" contexts. Calling API is an asynchronous event, that's why you will never know which API should return first. In your case, let say we have two API "user API" and "tweet API".

Currently in your code, you haven't had any constraint between "user context" and "tweet context".

"Ideally I would want to make the call on this route only after the username has been set." => from this point, you can think about checking before "tweet API" were called.

We can have some approaches depends on you:

- For that specific page (that page only for example), in the `render` function, return `null` for `TweetsComponent` whenever `user` has not been set. That makes, whenever `user` has been set, it re-renders the `TweetsComponent` component. "Tweet API" should be called after that.
- Customize your "tweet API" call to check if in the specific page, get `user` first, then call it. Basically the same flow like above.

Example code for my first approach:

```
const { setUsername } = useUserValue();

  const { username } = props.match.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsername(username);
  }, [setUsername, username]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {username ? <TweetsComponent /> : null}
    </div>
  );
```